# Use unique in data.table but keeping track of original rows (e.g. unique and then match)

Tags: r, data.table, match, unique

My first question to this wonderful community:

I want to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this but with a data.table:

```
# vector example
all <- c(4,4,2,1,2)
(uniq <- unique(all))
## [1] 4 2 1
match(all,uniq)
## [1] 1 1 2 3 2
```

The idea is to get all the unique rows from a data.table but, at the same time, to identify for each row of the original data.table to which row of the unique DT it matches. Maybe it is more clear with the example below.

**Edit:** My desire output is a data table with the unique rows AND a vector with the row positions of the original table in the unique-rows' table (i.e. a vector of length `nrow(dt)`)

This is the best solution that I've found so far:

```
library(data.table) # data.table 1.12.0
# small data.table example   ## edited to be reproducible 
m <- matrix(c(5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7, 5, 6, 6), nrow = 8, ncol = 2)
dt <- setDT(as.data.frame(m)) 
dt.uniq <- unique(dt)

#this returns the ID or position of the rows in the first table on the second table
match(transpose(dt), transpose(dt.uniq))
## [1] 1 1 2 2 3 2 4 4
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: Your data is not reproducible...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I edited the data and added a comment about my desire output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach with `data.table` version 1.12.4:

```
DT[, urow := unique(DT)[DT, on=.NATURAL, which=TRUE]]
```

output:

```
   V1 V2 urow
1:  7  5    1
2:  5  6    2
3:  6  5    3
4:  7  6    4
5:  7  7    5
6:  7  6    4
7:  7  5    1
8:  6  6    6
```

data:

```
library(data.table) #data.table_1.12.4
set.seed(9L)
DT <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(5:7, 16, replace = T), nrow = 8, ncol = 2))
DT
```

---

Edit to address comments:

1) `on=.NATURAL`

From `?data.table` under the Arguments section in `on`:

> When .NATURAL keyword provided then natural join is made (join on common columns).

That is, in `X[Y, on=.NATURAL]`, keys used for joining are columns that are **both** found in X and Y (`intersect(names(X), names(Y))`).

2) `which=TRUE`

From `?data.table` under the Arguments section in `which`:

> TRUE returns the row numbers of x that i matches to. If NA, returns the row numbers of i that have no match in x. By default FALSE and the rows in x that match are returned.

That is, the row indices of `x` (`unique(DT)` in OP) are returned from the join with `i` (`DT` here).

Comment: this worked perfectly after updating the data.table package. Just to know, can you explain me what `on = .NATURAL` and `which = TRUE` do?

Comment: @Fernando.-, i edited the post to address your qns.

Answer (score 0):

We can do a left join after adding a row column in `dt.uniq`

```
dt[dt.uniq[, row := seq_len(.N)], on = c('V1', 'V2')]

#   V1 V2 row
#1:  5  7   1
#2:  5  7   1
#3:  5  5   2
#4:  5  5   2
#5:  5  5   2
#6:  6  7   3
#7:  6  6   4
#8:  6  6   4
```

**data**

```
library(data.table)
m <- matrix(c(5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7, 5, 6, 6), nrow = 8, ncol = 2)
dt <- setDT(as.data.frame(m)) 
dt.uniq <- unique(dt)
```

Comment: any way of keeping the original row order in dt? the output is ordered by column "row"